# Trouble with pandas cut

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas time series data frame. df

date is the index.  Three columns, cusip, ticker, factor.

I want to decile the data per date.  About 100 factors per date...Each date will be deciled 1 to 10.

As a first attempt, I tried to decile the whole data frame regardless of date.  I used:

```
factor = pd.cut(df.factor, 10)  #This gave an error:

adj = (mx - mn) * 0.001 # 0.1% of the range
```

> Sybase.Error: ('Layer: 2, Origin: 4\ncs_calc: cslib user api layer: common library error: The conversion/operation resulted in overflow.')

The dataframe has 1mm rows.  Is it a size issue?  An nan issue?

Three questions.

1. What is wrong with the current function?
2. How do I get the count of number of nan's in a column?
3. Any recommendations on deciling per date?

Thank you for the help.  New to pandas python.

SAMPLE DATA:

```
df:             cusip      ticker    factor
date
2012-01-05       XXXXX       ABC       4.26
2012-01-05       YYYYY       BCD       -1.25
...(100 more stocks on this date)  
2012-01-06       XXXXX       ABC       3.25
2012-01-06       YYYYY       BCD       -1.55
...(100 more stocks on this date)
```

OUTPUT for what I would like:

```
#column with the deciles, lined up with the df.
decile
10
2
...
10
3
...
```

I can then append this to my dataframe to have a new column.  Each date is deciled and each data point then has their corresponding decile on that date.  Thanks.

Stack Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> File "/misc/apps/linux/python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pandas-0.10.0-py2.6-l‌​inux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1817, in transform res = wrapper(group)

File "/misc/apps/linux/python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pandas-0.10.0-py2.6-l‌​inux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1807, in <lambda> wrapper = lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwargs) File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda> File "/misc/apps/linux/python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pandas-0.10.0-py2.6-l‌​inux-x86_64.egg/pandas/tools/tile.py", line 138, in qcut bins = algos.quantile(x, quantiles)

File "/misc/apps/linux/python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pandas-0.10.0-py2.6-l‌​inux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 272, in quantile return algos.arrmap_float64(q, _get_score) File "generated.pyx", line 1841, in pandas.algos.arrmap_float64 (pandas/algos.c:71156) File "/misc/apps/linux/python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pandas-0.10.0-py2.6-l‌​inux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 257, in _get_score idx % 1)

File "/misc/apps/linux/python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pandas-0.10.0-py2.6-l‌​inux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 279, in _interpolate return a + (b - a) * fraction File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/Sybase.py", line 246, in _cslib_cb Sybase.Error: ('Layer: 2, Origin: 4\ncs_calc: cslib user api layer: common library error: The conversion/operation resulted in overflow.', <ClientMsgType object at 0x1c4da730>)
```

Comment: can you give some example data? That would make it easier to solve the problem.

Comment: Just added above.  Not sure how to format correctly.  Hopefully someone can help with that.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want the output to look like?  You mention wanting to decile by date. Your date looks like an index.  Is that correct? To count the number of NaNs you can use `df.factor.isnull().value_counts()`

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I want the output to be a column with the decile for that date.  Above you may have 10 and 2 next to the 2012-01-05 date and then 10 and 3 next to the 2012-01-06 date.

That's correct, it is an index.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toy example.  First make a `datetime` index.  Here I make an index using two days repeated 10 times each.  I then make some dummy data using `randn`.

```
In [1]: date_index = [datetime(2012,01,01)] * 10 + [datetime(2013,01,01)] * 10

In [2]: df = DataFrame({'A':randn(20),'B':randn(20)}, index=date_index)

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
                   A         B
2012-01-01 -1.155124  1.018059
2012-01-01 -0.312090 -1.083568
2012-01-01  0.688247 -1.296995
2012-01-01 -0.205218  0.837194
2012-01-01  0.700611 -0.001015
2012-01-01  1.996796 -0.914564
2012-01-01 -2.268237  0.517232
2012-01-01 -0.170778 -0.143245
2012-01-01 -0.826039  0.581035
2012-01-01 -0.351097 -0.013259
2013-01-01 -0.767911 -0.009232
2013-01-01 -0.322831 -1.384785
2013-01-01  0.300160  0.334018
2013-01-01 -1.406878 -2.275123
2013-01-01  1.722454  0.873262
2013-01-01  0.635711 -1.763352
2013-01-01 -0.816891 -0.451424
2013-01-01 -0.808629 -0.092290
2013-01-01  0.386046 -1.297096
2013-01-01  0.261837  0.562373
```

If I understand your question correctly, you want to decile *within* each date.  To do that, you can first move the index into the dataframe as a column.  Then, you can groupby by the new column (here it's called index), and use `transform` with a lambda function.  The lambda function below, applies `pandas.qcut` to the grouped `series` and returns the `labels` attribute.

```
In [4]: df.reset_index().groupby('index').transform(lambda x: qcut(x,10).labels)
Out[4]:
    A  B
0   1  9
1   4  1
2   7  0
3   5  8
4   8  5
5   9  2
6   0  6
7   6  3
8   2  7
9   3  4
10  3  6
11  4  2
12  6  7
13  0  0
14  9  9
15  8  1
16  1  4
17  2  5
18  7  3
19  5  8
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I tried your recommendation and got this error:

c.factor['2012'].reset_index().groupby('date').transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x,10).labels)

Sybase.Error: ('Layer: 2, Origin: 4\ncs_calc: cslib user api layer: common library error: The conversion/operation resulted in overflow.'

Any recommendations?  I subsetted by '2012' to make it a smaller df.  It has 100k rows now.

Also, small question - is there an easy fix to make it go from 1 to 10 versus 0 to 9?

Comment: Can you paste the entire stack trace?  Or is that the only error message you receive?  To return 1 to 10 just modify the lambda function like so: `lambda x: pd.qcut(x,10).labels + 1`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/misc/apps/linux/python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pandas-0.10.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1817, in transform
    res = wrapper(group)

Comment: File "/misc/apps/linux/python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pandas-0.10.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1807, in <lambda>
    wrapper = lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/misc/apps/linux/python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pandas-0.10.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/tools/tile.py", line 138, in qcut
    bins = algos.quantile(x, quantiles)

Comment: File "/misc/apps/linux/python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pandas-0.10.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 272, in quantile
    return algos.arrmap_float64(q, _get_score)
  File "generated.pyx", line 1841, in pandas.algos.arrmap_float64 (pandas/algos.c:71156)
  File "/misc/apps/linux/python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pandas-0.10.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 257, in _get_score
    idx % 1)

Comment: File "/misc/apps/linux/python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pandas-0.10.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 279, in _interpolate
    return a + (b - a) * fraction
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/Sybase.py", line 246, in _cslib_cb
Sybase.Error: ('Layer: 2, Origin: 4\ncs_calc: cslib user api layer: common library error: The conversion/operation resulted in overflow.', <ClientMsgType object at 0x1c4da730>)
>>>

Comment: I pasted your stack trace into your original question.  Hopefully someone with more knowledge can help you with that error.  Are you able to upgrade to python 2.7?

Comment: Does the number type matter?  I am getting a TypeError: Transform function invalid for data types.  Do I need to remove Nans?

Comment: It might.  Can you paste the output of `df.dtypes`?  WHere `df` is the dataframe you want to decile.  Also, you shouldn't have to drop the NaNs.  I believe the label that is returned is a -1.

Comment: When I dropped the NaNs, I was able to decile without a problem.  The numbers are listed as float64

Comment: That's odd.  I can use qcut on a float64 data frame with NaN's and it does not produce an error.